# Pycharm interpreter nothing to show

Tags: pycharm

I was using Pycharm in Mac and when I open my project from GitHub, Pycharm stopped prompting me:

[image]

Comment: You might be more comfortable posting at [ru.so]. Anyway, if you're posting here, please only post in English

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.